# Facebook sharing website issue with thumbnail

Tags: facebook, share, sharing

When I share a page from my website, I have ANY thumbnail attached to my post on Facebook. But, if I preview my page with the Facebook debug tool, Facebook is showing me the thumbnail.

You can try it here [developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object/](http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object/)
In the input URL put this page: http://www.team-exodia.fr/forum/threads/ouverture-de-la-section-garrys-mod-darkrp.6641/.

Now you see the thumbnail if the page is shared.
But now if you share this you didn't see the image preview on Facebook.

(**https://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.team-exodia.fr%2Fforum%2Fthreads%2Fouverture-de-la-section-garrys-mod-darkrp.6641%2F)**

This issue is all of my page on my forum. I don't understand.

Does anyone know what's happening here? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It works fine for me, although you do not have any Open Graph tags on your website. You should ALWAYS include them, the debugger tells you about that too. Here´s a nice list of the needed ones: http://ogp.me/

Dont´t forget to refresh the URL(s) in the debugger after changing it, the Facebook cache can be tricky.